# Unable to Execute external java script function in map reduce phase using mongo db

Tags: mongodb

I am working with hll js to merge two hll in mongo db,hll js provide that support but when i m using the hll functions inside the map function in mongo db it is giving refrence is not defined error

js file is included using load command in mongo shell which contain hll js and hll js functions are accesible from the local functions but not from map function

Pasting Code below

```
var mapFunction1 = function() {
var hllSet = hll.fromHexString(this.unique_imsi_hll).hllSet;
   emit(this.shape_id, hllSet);
};

var reduceFunction1 = function(key, values) {
   return Array.sum(values);
};


db.test_data.mapReduce(
   mapFunction1,
   reduceFunction1,
   { out: "inline" }
)
```

“errmsg” : “MapReduce internal error :: caused by :: ReferenceError: hll is not defined :\n@:2:5\n”,

Comment: The map function is run in the MongoDB server, not the client.  I doubt the the database node has included the hll code.

Comment: i have solved the problem for using any global variable in map reduce we need to use the scope parameter